# Selecting a radio button using selenium webdriver java when out of view

Tags: java, selenium

When I am running the below code run, it only works if I actually manage to scroll to the radio button to get it on the screen in time, otherwise the radio button is not selected.

HTML

```
<label><input name="GenericID1" type="radio" value="5625">&nbsp;Sample;|&nbsp;Sat/15/805B</label>
```

WebDriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://samplewebste.com");
WebElement oCheckBoxTest = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='5625']"));
oCheckBoxTest.click();
```

Does anyone have any idea why I actually have to manually scroll to the radio to get it to select actually work, otherwise the command just seems to be ignored without throwing any exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code to scroll to required element and click on it:

```
WebElement oCheckBoxTest = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='5625']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(oCheckBoxTest);
actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

If it not works, try with `JavaScript`:

```
WebElement oCheckBoxTest = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='5625']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", oCheckBoxTest);
oCheckBoxTest.click()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I think it works (but I've not got it to yet), but I am clicking a drop down tab to reveal this, and by doing that, it does some animation of scrolling. This means that even when I scroll down it flicks back up immediately. Are you able to advise on how I would delay the scroll by a second or so?

Comment: I'm not sure that I clearly understand what you mean.. Can you tell exact actions sequence you need to perform check-box click manually? Also piece of screenshot of your drop-down menu can be helpful

Comment: Hi there, I can't actually send a screenshot as it would contain sensitive information unfortunately. Basically I need to click an element, wait 2 seconds, then scroll. clicking the element reveals these radio buttons and actions some auto scroll which conflicts with the scroll you've implemented in the above code. By delaying the scroll by 2 seconds, the autoscroll will have finished its business and the scroll in the code will be able to continue without interference. Does that make sense?